# ForegroundService is not working on background depending on device

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to count step count when app is closed or on background all the times with `Kotlin` in Android device.

So I use `Service` with `notification` to run 24/7 like below.

In `onCreate` and `onStart` and `onStartCommand`, I register `sensorManager` to count step and call notification in order to run it on background and app is closed.

And step is counted in `onSensorChanged`.

My Service code is below, please look it through.

```
class MyService : Service(), SensorEventListener {

    private val db = Firebase.firestore
    private val userDB = Firebase.firestore.collection("users")
    private val diaryDB = Firebase.firestore.collection("diary")
    private val userId = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.uid

    private var todayStepCountFromDB = 0

    //    lateinit var diaryUpdateBroadcastReceiver: DiaryUpdateBroadcastReceiver
    lateinit var dateChangeBroadcastReceiver: DateChangeBroadcastReceiver
    lateinit var deviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver: DeviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver
    lateinit var stepCountBroadcastReceiver: StepCountBroadcastReceiver

    companion object {
        lateinit var sensorManager: SensorManager
        lateinit var step_sensor: Sensor

        const val ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION =
            "com.chungchunon.chunchunon_android.STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION"

        var todayTotalStepCount: Int? = 0
        const val STEP_THRESHOLD: Double = 6.5

        const val stepCountSharedPref = "stepCountSharedPreference"
        const val dateChangeSharedPref = "dateChangeSharedPref"
    }

    lateinit var prefs: SharedPreferences

    private var startingStepCount: Int = 0
    private var stepCount: Int = 0


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        StepCountNotification(this, todayTotalStepCount)

        // 기본
        sensorManager =
            applicationContext?.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        step_sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, step_sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)

        // 오늘 걸음수 초기화
        userDB.document("$userId").get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            var todayStepCountFromDB = document.getLong("todayStepCount") ?: 0
            todayTotalStepCount = todayStepCountFromDB.toInt()
            StepCountNotification(this, todayTotalStepCount)
        }

        // shared preference 설정
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(stepCountSharedPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        var dummyData = prefs.getInt(userId, 0)
        var datePrefs = getSharedPreferences(dateChangeSharedPref, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        // DateChangeBroadcastReceiver : 매일 걸음수 0
        dateChangeBroadcastReceiver = DateChangeBroadcastReceiver()
        val dateChangeIntent = IntentFilter()
        dateChangeIntent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)
        applicationContext?.registerReceiver(dateChangeBroadcastReceiver, dateChangeIntent)

        // DeviceShutDownBroadcastReceiver : 핸드폰 꺼질 때
        deviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver = DeviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver()

        val deviceShutdownIntent = IntentFilter()
        deviceShutdownIntent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN)
        applicationContext?.registerReceiver(deviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver, deviceShutdownIntent)

        // StepCountBroadcastReceiver : 디비 저장

        stepCountBroadcastReceiver = StepCountBroadcastReceiver()


        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext).registerReceiver(
            stepInitializeReceiver,
            IntentFilter("NEW_DATE_STEP_ZERO")
        );
    }

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(sensorEvent: SensorEvent?) {

        startingStepCount = prefs.getInt(userId, 0)
        stepCount = sensorEvent!!.values[0].toInt()
        val editor = prefs.edit()

        db.collection("user_step_count").document("$userId")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document.exists()) {
                    var snapShot = document.data

                    var dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                    var cal = Calendar.getInstance()
                    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)
                    var yesterday = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())

                    if (snapShot!!.containsKey("dummy") && snapShot!!.containsKey(yesterday)) {
                        // 더미값 존재
                        var dummyStepCount = (snapShot["dummy"] as Long).toInt()

                        todayTotalStepCount = stepCount - dummyStepCount

                        var intentToFirebase = Intent(this, StepCountBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
                        intentToFirebase.setAction(ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION)
                        intentToFirebase.putExtra("todayTotalStepCount", todayTotalStepCount)
                        sendBroadcast(intentToFirebase)

                        StepCountNotification(this, todayTotalStepCount)


                        var intentToMyDiary = Intent(ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION).apply {
                            putExtra(
                                "todayTotalStepCount",
                                todayTotalStepCount
                            )
                        }
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext!!)
                            .sendBroadcast(intentToMyDiary)


                        Log.d(
                            "걸음수 체크체크 2",
                            "stepCount: ${stepCount} // startingStepCount: ${dummyStepCount}"
                        )

                    } else {
                        // 더미값 존재 x

                        var newDummySet = hashMapOf(
                            "dummy" to stepCount
                        )
                        db.collection("user_step_count").document("$userId")
                            .set(newDummySet, SetOptions.merge())

                        StepCountNotification(this, 0)

                        var intentToFirebase = Intent(this, StepCountBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
                        intentToFirebase.setAction(ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION)
                        intentToFirebase.putExtra("todayTotalStepCount", 0)
                        sendBroadcast(intentToFirebase)

                        var intentToMyDiary = Intent(ACTION_STEP_COUNTER_NOTIFICATION).apply {
                            putExtra(
                                "todayTotalStepCount",
                                0
                            )
                        }
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext!!)
                            .sendBroadcast(intentToMyDiary)
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(p0: Sensor?, p1: Int) {
        Log.d("서비스", "accuracychanged")
    }

    override fun onStart(intent: Intent?, startId: Int) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId)

        sensorManager.registerListener(this, step_sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)

        StepCountNotification(this, todayTotalStepCount)

        // 기본
        sensorManager =
            applicationContext?.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        step_sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, step_sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)

        // 오늘 걸음수 초기화
        userDB.document("$userId").get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            var todayStepCountFromDB = document.getLong("todayStepCount") ?: 0
            todayTotalStepCount = todayStepCountFromDB.toInt()
            StepCountNotification(this, todayTotalStepCount)
        }

        // DateChangeBroadcastReceiver : 매일 걸음수 0
        dateChangeBroadcastReceiver = DateChangeBroadcastReceiver()
        val dateChangeIntent = IntentFilter()
        dateChangeIntent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)
        applicationContext?.registerReceiver(dateChangeBroadcastReceiver, dateChangeIntent)

        // DeviceShutDownBroadcastReceiver : 핸드폰 꺼질 때
        deviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver = DeviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver()

        val deviceShutdownIntent = IntentFilter()
        deviceShutdownIntent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN)
        applicationContext?.registerReceiver(deviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver, deviceShutdownIntent)

        // StepCountBroadcastReceiver : 디비 저장
        stepCountBroadcastReceiver = StepCountBroadcastReceiver()

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext).registerReceiver(
            stepInitializeReceiver,
            IntentFilter("NEW_DATE_STEP_ZERO")
        );
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        sensorManager.registerListener(this, step_sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)

        StepCountNotification(this, todayTotalStepCount)

        // 기본
        sensorManager =
            applicationContext?.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        step_sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, step_sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)

        // 오늘 걸음수 초기화
        userDB.document("$userId").get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            var todayStepCountFromDB = document.getLong("todayStepCount") ?: 0
            todayTotalStepCount = todayStepCountFromDB.toInt()
            StepCountNotification(this, todayTotalStepCount)
        }

        // DateChangeBroadcastReceiver : 매일 걸음수 0
        dateChangeBroadcastReceiver = DateChangeBroadcastReceiver()
        val dateChangeIntent = IntentFilter()
        dateChangeIntent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)
        applicationContext?.registerReceiver(dateChangeBroadcastReceiver, dateChangeIntent)

        // DeviceShutDownBroadcastReceiver : 핸드폰 꺼질 때
        deviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver = DeviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver()

        val deviceShutdownIntent = IntentFilter()
        deviceShutdownIntent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN)
        applicationContext?.registerReceiver(deviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver, deviceShutdownIntent)

        // StepCountBroadcastReceiver : 디비 저장
        stepCountBroadcastReceiver = StepCountBroadcastReceiver()

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext).registerReceiver(
            stepInitializeReceiver,
            IntentFilter("NEW_DATE_STEP_ZERO")
        );
        return START_STICKY
    }


    var stepInitializeReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            StepCountNotification(context!!, 0)
        }
    }

    private fun StepCountNotification(context: Context, stepCount: Int?) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val CHANNEL_ID = "my_app"
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "MyApp", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            )
            (context.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(
                channel
            )
            var decimal = DecimalFormat("#,###")
            var step = decimal.format(stepCount)

            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_new_alarm_icon)
                .setContentTitle("$step 걸음")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setShowWhen(false)
                .build()
            startForeground(1, notification)
        }
    }


}
```

In case of `DateChangeBroadcastReceiver`, I create broadcast receiver to reset step count to 0 when 00:00 in new date.

And I call this in `Activity` after checking ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission:

```
 userDB.document("$userId").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                var userType = document.data?.getValue("userType").toString()

                if (userType != "파트너") {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION,
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
                    ) {
                        //ask for permission
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            this,
                            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION),
                            100
                        )
                    } else {
                        var startService = Intent(this, MyService::class.java)

                        //오레오 이상부터 동작하는 코드
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                            startForegroundService(startService);
                        } else {
                            startService(startService);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

So I install this app in 4 android devices.

Three of them are working well, when I close the app or app goes on background, step is well counted and notification is showing on device.

But one device is stopped after working fine for a while.

1-2 days works perfect, but after a couple of days, count is stopped.

I don't know why this not working since I search how to make app work on background all on google and stack overflow and apply all to my code.

I have struggled with this problem for almost 2 months..

I really need your help, just some advice or guess is also helpful.

If you need more information, I can add that on real time.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreground services don't last forever.  They aren't meant to.  You say it works for 1-2 days, honestly that's longer than I would have expected.  If you want something to run constantly in the background without being killed-  you don't want Android as your OS.  It doesn't allow for that.  Or at the very least, you'd need a customized version of Android.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm a newbie to Kotlin so I don't get last part, 'you'd need a customized version of Android' -> How to make it? can you elaborate it?

Comment: @Hyejung Custom ROM OR your app is signed with manufacturer keys & custom permission OR possibly Mobile Device Management (MDM) / Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM) white list. If your app is for a consumer device, it will be killed. Also be aware of https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Android don't allow services to run infinitely. Service will be killed if app is close.
You can try these but none of them is proper solution

1. Register for different broadcast receiver and when intent receive, start service if service is not working.
2. Another solution is to create widget which will run and count steps. Widgets don't need an app to run all the time but widget need to be placed on user phone start screen by user to widget start working